# using count and inner join to aggregate data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to adapt a query for counting lines shipped on invocies, and point instead to my transfers table (instead of invocies). I am having troubles with the alias used originally and need help re writing this query that is failing on me please!

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id.line_id) 
FROM warehouse_transfer_d AS id
INNER JOIN warehouse_transfer_h AS th ON th.transfer_id = id.transfer_id
INNER JOIN item AS i ON i.item_id = id.item_id
WHERE 
    th.warehouse_id = 1
    AND th.ship_date BETWEEN '2015-02-16' AND '2015-02-22'
    AND i.non_stock != 'Y'
    AND ship_qty > 0
```

I am getting a failure on the (id.line_id)  as the alias.

thanks for help, sorry I am a noob!

Comment: Just use `COUNT(*)`.